# Advanced CSS Nav Hover

Tags: html, css

See here for my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/126/

My issue is that I want to be able to hover on the anchor and the li and achieve one hover state if that make sense.

Currently if you hover over the blue section the blue is only visible ( this is the li ) and if you hover over the anchor the li and anchor hover appears - please note that this is correct however, I only want this hover state when a user hovers over the anchor.

If the user were to hover over the list item then nothing should appear.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>  
    <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>  
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 13px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    height: 51px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 35px 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;                
}
    #nav li:hover {
        background: blue;    
}
#nav li:hover a {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #2596c0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You only want *what* hover state when the anchor is hovered over? The whole link to be blue, or red..? And, just a suggestion, but if a diamond-mod edits your question to *add* code it's probably best, when editing, to *correct the wrong code* but don't remove the code. Really, we *love* external live demos, but we'd prefer the relevant code to be *here* in the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas I want both states on hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the understanding that you want the blue and the red when hovering over the `li` (regardless of hovering over the `a` as well), then simply specify the `:hover` pseudo-class on the `li` and use the descendant selector to target the `a` element:

```
#nav li:hover a {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #2596c0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FvBqA/367/).